# Lazy load modules on same path based on role

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I am trying to load an Angular Module based on my role (when I am logged in). I tried it with an Angular Guard but that is not working, when it fails it does not go to the next route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => AuthModule
      // Load when not logged in
   },

   {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => AdminModule
      // Load when admin
   },

   {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => CrewModule
      // Load when crew
   }
];
```

Any ideas for how to fix this? I think an Angular Guard or using a matcher is not the right solution for this...

Edit: For each path/module I have my own guard looking like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanLoad, CanActivate, Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@app/core';

@Injectable()
export class AdminModuleGuard implements CanLoad {
   constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

   canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
      const url: string = route.path;
      console.log('Admin Module Load Guard - Url:' + url);
      return false;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Kind regrands,
Yanick

Comment: What exactly did you implement as the logic for your Guard? I think you can specify two different routes for both the modules and then navigate to a particular one based on the role of the user in the guard logic itself.

Comment: Definitely Angular Guard is the solution for this, is exactly what it does: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: @SiddAjmera Edited post with one of the guards

Comment: @fmontes But when the first guard fails, lets say 'AuthModule' is does not check if the next guard will pas or fail. 

Am I correct?

Comment: So in your case is like a it will check if user is login, then if its admin or crew, right? If that's the case, you can create a guard for admin and admin that can use a service that will check first if the user is login and then what role it have, there are several tutorials on this role based guards, but here is one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/03/07/angular-how-to-implement-role-based-security/

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? Looking to use a similar setup for Universal where the authenticated user gets the page as normal and an unauthenticated user gets the 'advert' style page. Makes URL sharing/SEO easier and hopefully make some development (reuse) for 'try it out' type of functionality on advert pages.

Comment: @Charly Unfortunately I didn't and went with the approach for different URLs :(

Comment: @Charly I have a working solution for this problem – see my answer below. I have also included a git repo with working code. Let me know if you get a chance to try it out.

Comment: @Digitrance Sorry, don't see any answers. I forgot I asked this a while back, but just came up with a solution that would solve this a couple weeks ago, involving a `canActivate` guard being applied to each route that then swaps out the component the router is attempting to load in-flight. Is this what you came up with? I can post an answer to this with a slimmed down example if it is different.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is being reviewed at the moment. In the meantime, you can play with it on Stackblitz. Here's the link – https://stackblitz.com/github/gulsharan/lazy-loaded-modules-for-same-route. My solution involves adding conditional logic to the single route itself, and lazy-load a specific module based on some asynchronous check.

Comment: You can find the explanation on my git repo – https://github.com/gulsharan/lazy-loaded-modules-for-same-route

Comment: That's awesome! I like it. The only thing I saw was the dashboard auth guard is ignored if you route to the dashboard before signing in -- loads an empty route. This is due to the guard needs to be on the lazy loaded module's router as it's the route actually being tested. I figured the `canActivateChild` would get but seemingly doesn't :\

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using your root module's `Injector` to access your `AuthService` instance, and then make an asynchronous decision to load one module or the other based on user's role. You can access the `Injector` immediately after the bootstrapping in your `main.ts` file, and then publish as an RxJs subject (say mySubject$) and then use this subject in your route definition.

```js
// Get root module's injector and publish it via RxJs subject
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then((m) => mySubject$.next(m.injector)) // <-- here
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

You can find a working example of this approach on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/gulsharan/lazy-loaded-modules-for-same-route)

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.