# Multiple views for multiple users

Tags: angular

I want to create custom view of `home` page based on user role.

Based on [this](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776177/how-to-define-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-for-your-angular-6-project/52634990#52634990) page I'm wondering if my app architecture should look like this:

```
(/app)
|-- modules
       |-- home
           |-- components
           |-- pages
           |    |-- home
           |         |-- role1
           |              |-- role1home.component.ts|html|scss|spec
           |         |-- role2
           |              |-- role2home.component.ts|html|scss|spec
           |
           |-- home-routing.module.ts
           |-- home.module.ts
```

Or rather like:

```
(/app)
|-- role1
     |-- home
     |     |-- home.component.ts|html|scss|spec
     |-- role1-routing.module.ts
     |-- role1.module.ts
|-- role2
    |-- home
    |     |-- home.component.ts|html|scss|spec
    |-- role2-routing.module.ts
    |-- role2.module.ts
```

Or any other way?

As far as I understand  I should avoid storing multiple views in one file and using them based on the `*ngIf`.

Another question is - If I would choose first approach how to redirect user to the proper view based on his role if I would have `auth.service.ts` which will return me on `auth.service.role()` his current role?

Should I do that in `home-routing.module.ts` on the `routes` section along with `routeGuard` using `canActivate`?

Comment: hi sobczi is your role is fixed I mean No of roles?
and one another questions is every role view has same Html or different?

Comment: what do you mean by fixed role? each role have different html

Comment: I mean no of roles, like 5 role 6 role ...etc..

Comment: I mean it is not yet implemented but in previous version of my project I have it.

Comment: IMO, second approach is more manageable. Also with second approach you can lay load modules according to role.

Comment: any tips how I should solve it? On routes in my ```app.module.ts``` I'm facing problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378649/lazy-load-modules-on-same-path-based-on-role)

Comment: @sobczi you need to implement guard for this. what is exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: I want to do it like: ```app.module.ts``` loads proper module depending on user role and then this loaded module routes user across app. So basically it would be like in the provided topic. ```path: '' ... canLoad:[false]``` and another would be ```canLoad:[true]``` but if first condition drops false then second one isnt executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the second structure is better because if you separate the pages into modules based on the role, you can load only the required modules for that specific role (use lazy loading) which will increase the performance of your website. This is what I normally do.

For the second question,I had a similar case where I had to integrate with a SSO end. So I believe you can redirect the user based on his role in the Authentication callback. You can also store the role for each page in the route data.

I hope this helps.